# Dynamically create database in SQL Server Express

Tags: c#, sql-server-express

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best practice to create (on demand) SQL Server 2008 Express databases in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2348839/best-practice-to-create-on-demand-sql-server-2008-express-databases-in-c)

In SQL Server Express (which is included with Visual Studio 2008), can I create a database dynamically at runtime? I mean create a database, not create a table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following question may help you with this:

[Best practice to create (on demand) SQL Server 2008 Express databases in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2348839/best-practice-to-create-on-demand-sql-server-2008-express-databases-in-c)

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can with the [Create Database](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en/library/ms176061.aspx) command.  It can run just as a normal SqlCommand.  You will have to supply a fully qualified path for the database path.

For you initial connection you can always connection to the master database.